# Integrate Visualvm with Eclipse (4.9) and JDK 10

Tags: java, eclipse, visualvm

I tried to integrate VisualVM with Eclipse (Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)) by follow the very basic instructions given [here](https://visualvm.github.io/idesupport.html). 
I run a windows machine, and have JDK 10 installed.
[Downloaded](https://visualvm.github.io/download.html) and unzipped VirtualVM

[image]

[Downloaded](https://github.com/oracle/visualvm/releases/download/1.4/visualvm_launcher_u2_eclipse.zip) and installed Virtual launcher plugin, and configured it as required:

[image]

Unfortunately the configuration can not be applied when configuration when JDK Home points to JDK 10.
It does accept JDK 1.8.

Any idea why and how can I set it to work with JDK 10 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a message that this bug was cleared in [this](https://github.com/oracle/visualvm/files/2724859/visualvm_launcher_u3_eclipse.zip) version of Eclipse launcher.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in the Eclipse VisualVM launcher. It would be great if you can file it at [VisualVM JIRA](https://github.com/oracle/visualvm/issues/new/choose). You found the correct workaround - just use JDK 8, there is no need to run VisualVM on JDK 10 if you have JDK 8 installed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The workaround is not that good because I use JavaFx which was decoupled from JDK 10.

Comment: I don't see, how this is connected to the fact that you want to run VisualVM on JDK 10. FYI: You don't need to run VisualVM on JDK 10 to be able to monitor JDK 10.